# Why is Gallium (III) Selenide naturally a P-type semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In one of the answers to my previous questions, I was told that intrinsic semiconductors are by definition neither P nor N type. However, Wikipedia says that Gallium (III) Selenide is P-type even when not doped. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Likely the common point defects cause this. However, one should look at the literature fir a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will point out that Ga2Se3 is not a nice neat crystal structure like, say, Si or even GaAs. While it is a zinc blende structure, 1/3 of the cation (Ga) sites are empty, and the ordering of vacancies has a large influence on the band structure.

For you particular question, you might start with [Energetics and kinetics of native point defects in Ga2Se3 from first principles](http://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.88.085203) (Gui-Yang Huang and B.D. Wirth, Phys Rev B88 085203 (2013)), where they calculate various defects and their properties. The authors note that both n-type and p-type doping has been observed. They also note that the Ga vacancy and Se on a Ga site are both shallow donors.